# How to do I split a string into hash keys with undef values?

Tags: perl

Here's my string:
    `NANA TEKA KAOE FLASK LSKK`

How do I make it so that it'll look like this:
    `HASH = {NANA => undef, TEKA => undef, KAOE => undef, ...`

Of course I could always split this into an array first
then loop through each value then assign them as hash
keys... but If there's a shorter/simpler way to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks for everyone's answers! Though @DavidO's answer was the simplest. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@hash{ split /\s+/, $string } = ();`

Comment: Thanks! Just what I was missing out: '@'

Comment: @DavidO: Do you happen to know whether there is a general solution of equal complexity (i.e. no explicit `map` etc.) for a constant value that is not `undef`?

Comment: musiKk, assign an expression involving the [`x` repetition operator](http://p3rl.org/op#Multiplicative-Operators): `… = ('foobar') x 5`

Answer (score 7):

You can split the string and use a map to generate the output hash.

```
my $string = "NANA TEKA KAOE FLASK LSKK";
my %hash = map { $_ => undef } split(/\s/, $string);
```

Answer (score 2):

I doubt if this is the most succinct way to do it, but it seems to work:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $string = "NAN TEKA KAOE FLASK LSKK";
my %hash = map { ($_ => undef) } split /\s+/, $string;

foreach my $key (keys %hash)
{
    printf "$key => %s\n", (defined($hash{$key})) ? $hash{$key} : "undef";
}
```