# Split mutli-element string into hash

Tags: perl

I know that one can easily split a string into a hash using `map` like this question [How to do I split a string into hash keys with undef values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223570/how-to-do-i-split-a-string-into-hash-keys-with-undef-values/8223593), or this [Perl Monks thread](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=887343).  So, something like this very easily works:

```
my %table = map { chomp; split(/\t/) } <DATA>;
dd \%table;

__DATA__
#1245   banana
#3499   cherry
#5290   notebook
#2112   compact_disc
```

Of course, this would result in:

```
{
  "#1245" => "banana",
  "#2112" => "compact_disc",
  "#3499" => "cherry",
  "#5290" => "notebook",
}
```

If one had a more complicated table of data, though, and wanted to make a hash of arrays using the second column as the key, is this possible with map, or does one have to use the "longer" form:

```
my %table;
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp(my @elems = split(/\t/));
    $table{$elems[1]} = \@elems;
}
dd \%table;

__DATA__
shelf1  #1245   banana  Dole
shelf1  #3499   cherry  Acme
shelf2  #5290   notebook    Staples
shelf3  #2112   compact_disc    Mercury_Records
```

to make:

```
{
  "#1245" => ["shelf1", "#1245", "banana", "Dole"],
  "#2112" => ["shelf3", "#2112", "compact_disc", "Mercury_Records"],
  "#3499" => ["shelf1", "#3499", "cherry", "Acme"],
  "#5290" => ["shelf2", "#5290", "notebook", "Staples"],
}
```

I tried these two approaches, but neither seem to work, and I'm guessing it's not possible.  But, just out of curiosity (and education) was wondering if one can do it a similar way.

```
my %table = map{ $_->[1] => @$_ } split(/\t/, <DATA>);
my %table = map{ split(/\t/); $_->[1], @$_ } <DATA>;
```

Comment: Define "didn't work". Did you get an error, if not what was the output instead of what you expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use map, but you need to move the split inside:

```
my %table = map { chomp; my @s = split /\t/; $s[1], \@s } <DATA>;
```

Comment: Oh!  I see how to do it now!  I had tried a similar approach, moving `split` inside the `map` in one of my other iterations, but was still trying to use `$_` and friends.  The other key to this is variable assignment inside the map.  Thanks @choroba!